# Web3.py _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault returned a result with an error set

Tags: web3.py, python

I am trying to read data from a pancakeswap contract and i started getting the `_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault returned a result with an error set` and would crash the thread and subsequently the process that the python script it's running on.

this happens with multiple contracts such : 0x51a0bCBd16eCe1C40768682bc892E04e1A162296, 0xA32A983a64ce21834221AA0AD1f1533907553136 on different official providers such : https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org/ and https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org

i am using the panckake pair abi from [here](https://bscscan.com/address/0xA32A983a64ce21834221AA0AD1f1533907553136#code) with the simple code :

```
pancakePair = w3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=load_abi(abi_file_name))
pancakePair.functions.getReserves().call()
```

this seems to happen randomly, with some calls out of so many but the script and process crashing is the issue, i do catch the error but the crash still happens. i would like to know the issue that causes that error, especially knowing that it traces back to web3py.

i am using `web3==5.19.0` version

if u can help with the crashing here is the report for the crashing thread

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000158
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [5564]
```

```
Thread 8 Crashed:
0   org.python.python               0x000000010963cd09 object___reduce_ex__ + 34
1   org.python.python               0x0000000109626501 cfunction_vectorcall_O + 280
2   org.python.python               0x000000010969dff3 call_function + 403
3   org.python.python               0x000000010969b230 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27624
4   org.python.python               0x00000001095f6648 function_code_fastcall + 97
5   org.python.python               0x000000010969dff3 call_function + 403
6   org.python.python               0x000000010969b184 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27452
7   org.python.python               0x000000010969eb3b _PyEval_EvalCode + 1998
8   org.python.python               0x00000001095f65d8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 248
9   org.python.python               0x00000001095f5e67 _PyObject_FastCallDictTstate + 212
10  org.python.python               0x00000001095f6891 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 139
11  org.python.python               0x000000010963e2fb slot_tp_call + 87
12  org.python.python               0x00000001095f5fa3 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 266
13  org.python.python               0x000000010969e027 call_function + 455
14  org.python.python               0x000000010969b184 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27452
15  org.python.python               0x00000001095f6648 function_code_fastcall + 97
16  org.python.python               0x000000010969dff3 call_function + 403
17  org.python.python               0x000000010969b168 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27424
18  org.python.python               0x000000010960452c gen_send_ex + 269
19  _asyncio.cpython-39-darwin.so   0x000000010a19ffea task_step + 559
20  _asyncio.cpython-39-darwin.so   0x000000010a1a108f TaskWakeupMethWrapper_call + 211
21  org.python.python               0x00000001095f5fa3 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 266
22  org.python.python               0x00000001096ad866 context_run + 180
23  org.python.python               0x0000000109626267 cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL_KEYWORDS + 124
24  org.python.python               0x000000010969b5a9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 28513
25  org.python.python               0x00000001095f6648 function_code_fastcall + 97
26  org.python.python               0x000000010969dff3 call_function + 403
27  org.python.python               0x000000010969b168 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27424
28  org.python.python               0x00000001095f6648 function_code_fastcall + 97
29  org.python.python               0x000000010969dff3 call_function + 403
30  org.python.python               0x000000010969b168 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27424
31  org.python.python               0x00000001095f6648 function_code_fastcall + 97
32  org.python.python               0x000000010969dff3 call_function + 403
33  org.python.python               0x000000010969b168 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27424
34  org.python.python               0x00000001095f6648 function_code_fastcall + 97
35  org.python.python               0x000000010969b4b4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 28268
36  org.python.python               0x00000001095f6648 function_code_fastcall + 97
37  org.python.python               0x000000010969dff3 call_function + 403
38  org.python.python               0x000000010969b168 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27424
39  org.python.python               0x00000001095f6648 function_code_fastcall + 97
40  org.python.python               0x000000010969dff3 call_function + 403
41  org.python.python               0x000000010969b168 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27424
42  org.python.python               0x00000001095f6648 function_code_fastcall + 97
43  org.python.python               0x00000001095f8337 method_vectorcall + 304
44  org.python.python               0x0000000109718acf t_bootstrap + 70
45  org.python.python               0x00000001096d8424 pythread_wrapper + 25
46  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20326950 _pthread_start + 224
47  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2032247b thread_start + 15
```

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem: Access violations randomly crash the script. I am multithreading pretty heavily but each thread has its own web3. I've tried 5.19 and 5.21, both have the same issue. I don't know a good way to debug this either. I'm using faulthandler but it doesn't give much in the way of useful output.

Comment: Sounds like there is something wrong with your Python interpreter and this is a Python bug, not related to web3.py. Try searching Python bug reports regarding similar crashes.

Comment: My issue turned out to be from the provider i was using. from a list of 10 providers, only a couple of them has this error. i ran light nodes and full nodes locally and this error wasn't there too. so try to change your provider or check if you are actually receiving the correct data format.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa it turns out that it is an error with the provider i was using. i didn't check exactly what the error origin is, but changing the provider actually fixed it.